# Is there any way to add Java Library in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Let say I am working on `RecyclerView` and Now in `RecyclerView` I want to load Image in `Asynchronously`. So I was search on Goolge and SO. I found [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/799/listview-asynchronous-image-loading-from-url) Thread.

In this thread discussion about Use this
library

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

But I don't know how to add this in my Project to work with it.

Any Help be Appreciated And Forgive me if this is silly question.

**UpDate :**

Now I have add the Library in  my Project.

and To Load Image I use below code

```
string url = Settings.Base_URLs + "User/SetUser/" + item.DoctorId;
ImageView image = vh.searchimage;
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(image, url);
```

But Image is not display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the UrlImageViewHelper from the Component store. Right click Components folder in your solution -> Get More Components -> Search for UrlImageViewHelper -> Add in the search box.

Also, have a look at Picasso component if you want asynchronous image download and cache.

You can use it as follows:

```
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (imageView, "http://example.com/image.png", Resource.Drawable.placeholder);
```

Comment: @Ironman I have updated my answer on the usage. For more help you can check out https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/urlimageviewhelper

Comment: I check out that but I want to get image from my server not from the Drawable folder.

Comment: @Ironman my answer explains a way of getting it from the server. The Resource.Drawable.placeholder is just a placeholder until the actual image gets downloaded. If the image still doesn't download, you might want to check if the image on the server actually exists and not corrupted.

Comment: and the server response give `base64` Image and I want to convert into `bitmap` and then set to my `ImageView` how to do that ?

Comment: @Ironman you might want to post a new question explaining the new issue you are facing. I will try and help you there. If you found my answer regarding your initial question about adding the library satisfactory and it worked for you please mark it as accepted. Also post the new question with the exact  issue as title, the response and error log if any

Comment: thanx for Help. First I will try myself then I post new Question.

Comment: @Ironman Sure. post the link to your new question as well if you need more help

Comment: @Ironman I am not sure if there is a fresh binding available for the new library. You can try this library https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso . Picasso is quite a powerful tool as well